# Show div one by one on page load using jQuery/CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page with multiple bootstrap columns, what I am trying is to appear the first six `div` which has `class=inner` to appear one by one when page load, this is what I have created here in [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/snuu1958/6/)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.main-wrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #cccccc;
}
.row {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
.col-md-3 {
    border: 1px solid #444;
}
.overflowH {
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>

<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function(){
    function setHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
        $('.fullH').css('height', windowHeight);
    };
    setHeight();
    $(window).resize(function() {
        setHeight();
    });
    $('.col-md-3').height( Math.round( $('.col-md-3').width() ) * Math.tan(0.523599) );
    $('.row').css('transform', 'skewY(-20deg)');
}
</script>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row fullH overflowH">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="inner">Text Here</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
      <div class="col-md-3">Text Here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: "one by one". Do you mean you want a delay between them appearing? If so, how long a delay?

Comment: Yes, delay between they appear, and delay should be .3 seconds or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css add: `.col-md-3.show { opacity: 1; transition: .2s; }`
javascript add:

```
$(".col-md-3").each(function(index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () { $this.addClass("show"); }, index * 200);
  });
```

try: https://jsfiddle.net/snuu1958/7/

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want. try this.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<style type="text/css">
 div.same{
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 5px solid yellow;
  display: none;
 }

 div#div1{
  background-color: orange;
 }
 div#div2{
  background-color: pink;
 }

 div#div3{
  background-color: purple;
 }
 div#div4{
  background-color: green;
 }
 div#div5{
  background-color: red;
 }
 div#div6{
  background-color: blue;
 }


</style>

<body>
 
<div class="same" id="div1"></div>
<div class="same" id="div2"></div>
<div class="same" id="div3"></div>
<div class="same" id="div4"></div>
<div class="same" id="div5"></div>
<div class="same" id="div6"></div>


 
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
 
 $(document).ready(function(){
  for(var i=0;i<6;i++)
  {
   var theid = $("#div"+i);
   var thetime = 800 *i;
   $(theid).show(thetime); // or use .fadeIn()
   thetime = thetime * i;
  }
 });



</script>
</html>
```